# Axios adds extra slash on get request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Axios adds extra slash on get request after the domain name, `https://DOMAIN_NAME//api/get`, but only when accessing via the domain name, not via local IP. When accessing via ip, it works fine.

I have tried remove the slash from on the server side, but it still has double slash. I have also tried turning off caching but no success.

If you have any ideas, please write then in an answer.

Comment: How are you constructing the query?

Comment: Can you provide the sample code how you can passing the domain name?

Comment: check you config or .env file where you are defining the domain name may be there you are giving slash